# Mutually exclusive jquery click events

Tags: jquery

Here I have two click events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //MESSAGES CHECKBOX
    $(document).on("click",".messages_checkbox",function () {
        alert("clicked box");
    });

    //MESSAGES ROW
    $(document).on("click",".messages_row",function () {
        alert("clicked");
    });

});
```

And here is the html:

```
<tr class="messages_row">";
<td><input type="checkbox" class="messages_checkbox" value="1"></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, one object is inside another. What I would like to do is fire mutually exclusive (either one or the other - never both) events when either the check box is clicked, or the container itself is clicked.

Right now both events fire if I click the checkbox, one after the other. I only want the checkbox event to fire.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click",".messages_checkbox",function () {
    alert("clicked box");

    // Stops the bubbling
    return false;
});

//MESSAGES ROW
$(document).on("click",".messages_row",function () {
    alert("clicked");

    // Stops the bubbling        
    return false;
});
```

Make sure to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729215/601179)

Comment: Oh, this improves performance then as well?

Comment: Does this work for delegated events now as well?

Comment: @FelixKling, when did it not?

Comment: @AmyNeville, a micro-optimization I would say, but yes. It's significantly better when use mousemove events and such where it can really be a bottle-neck.

Comment: Just tested it and it seems to work. But that was not always the case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7448860/218196. Or maybe this is/was only a problem when you didn't delegate the parent event handler.